# How to cherry-pick merge commits?

Tags: git

I need to cherry pick a range of commits, where I found commits like this:

```
Merge "TICKET-100: Some commit message" into master

< some other commits >

TICKET-100: Some commit message
```

I checked the content and its the same for both commits. Can I only cherry pick the first, and ignore the one starting with "Merge"? How are they related?

Comment: cherry-picking always works on individual commits. It's not clear what would force you to cherry-pick both at once.

Comment: you have to specify which difference is interesting (merge has to parents). You have to add parameter `-m 1` or  `-m 2` (this defines what is interesting difference against specific parent).

Comment: Anyway you have to choices: merge commits before merge, or merge sing merge commit specifying proper parent (then it will contains changes of all commits).

Comment: Shouldn't the tile of the question be "How NOT to cherry-pick merge commits?"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets assume you have something like this:

```
X - master
|
|
M
|\
| \
X  B - merged_feature_branch
|  |
|  |
X  A    X - cherry_pick_destination
| /     |
|/      |
X       X
|      /
|     /
```

Now you have two choices:

- cherry pick only `A` and `B`
- cherry pick `M` against first parent (`-m 1`)

Both solution will introduce same change, but IMHO first approach is more readable.
In case if some conflicts where resolved when committing `M` then second option may be preferred..

Comment: In the 2nd option, how do you determine the correct integer value to use for `-m`?

Comment: `-m X` defines index of a a parent for which difference is important. In this case where feature was merge into `master` it is `-m 1`. In case `master` was merged to feature branch then `master` fast forwarded it should be `-m 2`. Side note: it is possible to create merge commit with more then two parents, but nobody sane uses this possibility.

Comment: If merge happens from the same remote branch to feature branch, what is the value to put in X?

Comment: See [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt--mltparent-numbergt). This is index of parrent (starting form `1`), so `master` was merged into `feature` branch and  then `master` fast forwarded, next index is needed: `-m 2`. It is in comment above.

Answer (score 7):

If you have to cherry-pick a range of commits without the merge commits, rather than doing

```
git cherry-pick A..B
```

You can put the range into a subcommand where you suppress merge commits :

```
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --no-merges A..B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can rebase your commits before merging?
Try something like this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~[commits count]
```

Now you must see a list with chosen commits. Before the first commit, to which you want to squash all other commits, must be a command `pick`.

`squash` - if you want to change the commit message and `fixup` - if not.

After rebasing you probably can merge only chosen changing.